# PowerShell Start-Job with C++ exe file: Why are start and end times the same for each batch of 5 jobs?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, start-job

powershell running a c++ .exe using start-job cmdlet

```
$connectionstring = "Server=localhost;Database=testDB;Trusted_Connection=True;"

$connection=New-Object    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

$connection.ConnectionString=$connectionstring

$connection.Open()

$jobs=@()



 $count="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled='1'"



$maxConcurrentJobs=5

$jobsTotalresult=Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'localhost' -Database 'testDB' -Query $count

$jobsTotal=$jobsTotalresult.Column1




$SQLQueryID="SELECT ID FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"

$SQLIDCommand=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQueryID, $connection)



$SQLQuerySELECT="SELECT ExecPath, Param1, Param2, Param3 FROM Tasks WHERE Enabled=1"

$SQLselectCommand=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand ($SQLQuerySELECT, $connection)



$tID=$SQLIDCommand.ExecuteScalar()

      $SQLReader=$SQLselectCommand.ExecuteReader()



$data = @()

while($SQLReader.Read()){

$row = @{

    ExecPath = $SQLReader.GetString(0)

    Param1 = $SQLReader.GetString(1)

    Param2 = $SQLReader.GetString(2)

    Param3 = $SQLReader.GetString(3)

}

$data += New-Object PSObject -Property $row

$jobsTotal=$data.Count

}

$SQLReader.Close()





function JobCompleted($receivedState){

write-host 'JOBCOMPLETED WITH' $receivedState

if($receivedState -eq 'Completed'){

$Status=2

$Note="Task finished successfully '$jid'"

} elseif($receivedState -eq 'Failed') {

$Status=3

$Note="Task failed"



}elseif ($receivedState -ne 'Completed' -or $receivedState -ne 'Failed') {

 $Status=9

$Note="NOT DEFINED"



}

    $Finished=Get-Date

            $SQLQueryUPDATE="UPDATE TaskLogs SET Status=$Status, Finished='$Finished', Note='$Note' WHERE ID IN (SELECT TOP $maxConcurrentJobs ID FROM TaskLogs ORDER BY ID DESC)"

    $SQLUPDATEcmd=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryUPDATE, $connection)

    $SQLUPDATEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

}







foreach($currow in $data){





 while(($jobs | Where-Object{$_.State -eq 'Running'}).Count -ge $maxConcurrentJobs){

Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500}

    $env:Path=$currow.ExecPath

    $job=Start-Job {& $env:Path}

    $jobs+=$job

    $Created=Get-Date

    foreach($runningjob in $job){

    if($runningjob.State -eq 'Running'){

    $Status=1

    $Note="Task is running "

   

    }

    $SQLQueryWRITE="INSERT INTO TaskLogs(tID, Status, Created, Finished, Note) Values($tID, $Status, '$Created', null, '$Note')"

        $SQLWRITEcmd=New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SQLQueryWRITE, $connection)

        $SQLWRITEcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

     

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $runningjob StateChanged -Action {

    $currentState=$EventArgs.JobStateInfo.State

   



    JobCompleted($currentState); Unregister-Event $eventsubsciber.SourceIdentifier

    }

   

    }

    }
```

Hello,
This is my script in which the previous problem I had was running 5 by 5 jobs out of 20.
Now I am using a cpp file (.exe) which I wrote that just randomises time, writes it out and pauses the program for that time. I need this test because in the production environment not all jobs will take the same time.
But when I run it with this I get jobs that begin and end at the same time and the time written out when I receive a job is the same time for all five jobs, so the time is same per batch, the next five has different time compared to first five but within those five again the time is the same.
Can anyone explain what is the situation here and why that happens?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the language you wrote your executable in is relevant, don't you think that the code also would be?

Comment: @molbdnilo you mean the c++ code? I didn’t think it would be relevant since that works fine just randomizes a number then sleep(number)

Comment: SQL Server is a multi-threaded data base.  When you have more than one query executing they are running in parallel and also have locks to make sure there aren't any conflicts.  Most Windows machines have more than one core in the microprocessor also allowing a degree of parallelism.  There is also a connection pool to allow more than one connection between client and database.  I suspect because the locks in the database are preventing conflicts the update is waiting until the selects are completed.

Comment: @jdweng but why is my cpp output the same, when i receive a job even when i run it without sql part, im guessing its something in how the start job cmdlet functions

Comment: @jdweng it seem that you are correct, sql database is the one making the issue, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Is it really an issue that needs to be fixed?  A multi-user database needs to contain locks so errors do not occur.  If the data base has only ten items in stock and one order needs 6 items and the other needs 5 items can you issue 11 items when there is only 10 in stock?

Comment: @jdweng i need to know the time it takes for each job respectively to finish

Comment: So you already getting the times, you just don't like the results.  It doesn't mean they are wrong or need to be fixed.

Comment: @jdweng not that i dont like them but they do not make any sense, and i dont know where is the issue

Comment: It is inside the database.  You can always check the log files using SQL Server Management Studio in the explorer under management.  I suspect you are doing queries in parallel and multiple locks are being placed on the processes.  Then the lock are unlocking at the same time so it looks like all the processes are ending at same time.